# Read File line by line from bottom to top but loosing encoding

Tags: c#

We have situation where we need to read file line by line from bottom to top for which the code is as bellow

```
private IEnumerable<string> readFile(string fName)
    {
        using (FileStream reader = new FileStream(fName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            int i = 0;
            StringBuilder lineBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            int byteRead;
            while (-i < reader.Length)
            {
                reader.Seek(--i, SeekOrigin.End);
                byteRead = reader.ReadByte();
                if (byteRead == 10 && lineBuffer.Length > 0)
                {
                    yield return ReverseString(lineBuffer.ToString());
                    lineBuffer.Remove(0, lineBuffer.Length);
                }
                lineBuffer.Append((char)byteRead);
            }
            yield return ReverseString(lineBuffer.ToString());
            reader.Close();
        }
    }

    public static string ReverseString(string s)
    {
        char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        return new string(arr);
    }
```

The above code works fine for ASCII but for utf-8 encoded file the content is messed up and not readable.

Comment: What you meant by `does not work` are you getting any error or exception?

Comment: use File.WriteAllLines it has overloaded method for  Encoding.UTF8

Comment: @un-lucky: The content is messed up and not readable for utf-8 encoded files

Comment: @viveknuna: we have to read file from bottom to top line by line

Comment: EDIT
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename, Encoding.UTF8).Select(line => new string(line.Reverse().ToArray())).Reverse().ToList();

Comment: foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("ReverseRead.txt", Encoding.UTF8).Reverse())
        {
            if (noNeedToReadFurther)
                break;

            // process line here
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

Comment: BTW—you might want to revise your spec to reverse [text elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/631ac68y(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) instead of [UTF-16 code units](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-1) ([Char](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

```
var filename = "file.txt";
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename, Encoding.UTF8).Select(line => new string(line.Reverse().ToArray())).Reverse().ToList();
```

For an Enumerable it should be

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filename, Encoding.UTF).Reverse().Select(x => new string(x.Reverse().ToArray()));
```

Comment: I have this idea but as mentioned in the code i am using yeild to not to load entire file in memory but just read a line and return it.

Comment: `Encoding.UTF8` is redundant since "normal" files are UTF-8. But, yes, the key here is to use _text_ functions when reading text.